# How to implement one select/deselect all button while above tableview in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement the select/deselect all functionality on one buttons that tableview cell all button must get selected and deselect as per user interaction. I am having selected array and unselected array, while selecting through tableview cell button. Below given code where tableview cell button clicked on cellar row at indexPath method.

```
NSMutableDictionary *d=[_studentArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.studentId.text=[[d objectForKey:@"student_id"]description];
cell.rollNum.text=[[d `enter code here`objectForKey:@"class_roll_no"]description];
cell.firstName.text=[[d objectForKey:@"first_name"]description];
cell.lastName.text=[[d objectForKey:@"last_name"]description];
cell.attendanceStatus.text=[[d objectForKey:@"status"]description];
cell.studentFullName.text=[[[d objectForKey:@"first_name"]description] stringByAppendingString:[[d objectForKey:@"last_name"]description]];
NSLog(@"studentFullName.text=%@ status=%@",cell.studentFullName.text,cell.attendanceStatus.text);

NSLog(@"Student array count=%ld",_studentArr.count);


cell.studentSelectBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
NSLog(@"Selectted cell indexpath===%ld",(long)cell.studentSelectBtn.tag);
[cell.studentSelectBtn setTag:indexPath.row];

[cell.studentSelectBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(studentselectBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if ([selectedArr containsObject:self.studentArr[indexPath.row]]) {
    [cell.studentSelectBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedAttendance.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.studentSelectBtn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    NSLog(@"attendance Status in checked ===%@",cell.attendanceStatus.text);
    NSLog(@"selected array count=%ld",selectedArr.count);
}
else{

    [cell.studentSelectBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.studentSelectBtn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    NSLog(@"attendance status in unchecked====%@",cell.attendanceStatus.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing how you currently add/remove entries to `selectedArr`, but from what you did show, you could wire these two methods up as the targets of your "Select All" / "Deselect All" buttons:

```
-(void) selectAll {
    self.selectedArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.studentArr];
    [self.unselectArr removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void) deselectAll {
    [self.selectedArr removeAllObjects];
    [self.unselectedArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.studentArr];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I am having unselected array.Please find below details:   
    NSMutableArray *unselectedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_studentArr];
    [unselectedArray removeObjectsInArray:selectedArr];
    NSLog(@"*****unselectedArray=%@",unselectedArray);

Comment: added it to my answer

Comment: both methods i need to call in button click ri8?

Comment: Still not working.Please share me any alternative solution.